# Visual Studio 2010 vs. Visual Studio 2013 - Different Compiler Errors - Why?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

We noticed something strange we couldn't explain. In a class we had these 2 functions:

```
   Public Overloads Shared Function ToList(ByVal input As Object, _
                                    Optional ByVal StringSeparator As String = ";", _
                                    Optional ByVal CharacterCasing As String = "", _
                                    Optional ByVal StartRow As Integer = 0, _
                                    Optional ByVal EndRow As Integer = -1) As String
            ...
   End Sub

   Public Overloads Shared Function ToList(ByVal Input As Object, _
                            Optional ByVal SplitStringSeparator As String = ",", _
                            Optional ByVal JoinStringSeparator As String = ",", _
                            Optional ByVal PreFixStr As String = "", _
                            Optional ByVal PostFixStr As String = "") As String
           ...
  End Sub
```

If we try to compile this project in VS2013 we don't get any errors. If we try to compile this same exact project in VS 2010 it gives the following error (which makes sense):

> Error 1   'Public Shared Overloads Function ToList(input As Object,
>   [StringSeparator As String = ";"], [CharacterCasing As String = ""],
>   [StartRow As Integer = 0], [EndRow As Integer = -1]) As String' and
>   'Public Shared Overloads Function ToList(Input As Object,
>   [SplitStringSeparator As String = ","], [JoinStringSeparator As String
>   = ","], [PreFixStr As String = ""], [PostFixStr As String = ""]) As String' cannot overload each other because they differ only by the
>   default values of optional parameters
>
> Error 2   'Public Shared Overloads Function ToList(input As Object,
>   [StringSeparator As String = ";"], [CharacterCasing As String = ""],
>   [StartRow As Integer = 0], [EndRow As Integer = -1]) As String' and
>   'Public Shared Overloads Function ToList(Input As Object,
>   [SplitStringSeparator As String = ","], [JoinStringSeparator As String
>   = ","], [PreFixStr As String = ""], [PostFixStr As String = ""]) As String' cannot overload each other because they differ only by the
>   types of optional parameters.

Anyone have a good explanation of why there would be a difference when opening the SAME solution containing the SAME project in different versions of VS sometimes gives errors and sometimes not?

Comment: Because Visual Studio 2013 uses `Roslyn compiler` and Visual Studio 2010 doesn't?

Comment: Both the same versions of .NET?

Comment: @lll - Roslyn is not released yet, so no....

Comment: yes, everything exactly the same. Same solution/same project/same .vb file... In fact we just have 2 VS installed (VS2010 & VS2013) and opening the same solution in different versions.

Comment: In VS2013 you instead get an error in the caller if the call is ambiguous.  For example try to call `ToList(blah)` and you see the following: "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'ToList' is most specific for these arguments."  Apparently they wanted to allow this scenario as long as you make sure every particular call is unambiguous.  That still doesn't explain though *how* this behavior can be different between VS2010 and VS2013...

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Was guessing but I believe that it may not be released yet but it is using Roslyn underneath it http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/12/17/microsoft_roslyn_dogfooding/

Comment: @mellamokb I just tested that too, confirmed.. Interestingly, it appears to contravene the [spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234437.aspx), "Overloaded type members must possess unique signatures." and "The signature of a method specifically does not include the return type or parameter modifiers such as Optional, ByRef or ParamArray."

Comment: The best hint I can find is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc714070(v=vs.110).aspx under Overload Resolution. It certainly doesn't match exactly, but if you leave out the optional parameters than the signatures are identical and likely threw a compile-time error until VS 2012.

Comment: If I manually call `MSBuild` from a command-line in the VS2010 solution, it builds fine.  So it seems to be a rule present only in VS2010 IDE that was removed in VS2013.  **EDIT:** Actually, this is only true on a machine that has both VS2010 and VS2013 installed.  On a machine with just VS2010 installed, MSBuild generates the same two errors.  So it appears that installing VS2013 includes an updated compiler that differs from the behavior of the VS2010 IDE!

Comment: @lll - That means they're using Roslyn in their own development, not that Roslyn is in VS2013..     Roslyn is not yet released, and it's not in 2013... at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the compiler source code as available through the Reference Source, I think I see it accepting the second function as a valid overload because the default value has a different type.  You can have a look-see for yourself, vb\language\compiler\symbols\symboltable.cpp, BCSYM::CompareParams() function.

```
    // make sure the types being used for the default are the same
    if ( ParmTypeCompareFlags & ( EQ_Shape | EQ_GenericTypeParams ))
    {
        ComparisonFlags |= EQ_OptionalTypes;

        // don't percolate the difference in the type shape on in this case - the difference we care about it is EQ_OptionalTypes
        ParmTypeCompareFlags &= ~(EQ_Shape | EQ_GenericTypeParams);   // <== Here
    }
```

Turning off EQ_Shape is the bug, that indicates that the parameter is different.  I can't compare it with the way it was done in VS2010, that version is not available.

This of course doesn't make sense.  And it violates chapter 4.1.1 of the language specification which says:

> A method with optional parameters is considered to have multiple signatures, one for each set of parameters that can be passed in by the caller. For example, the following method has three corresponding signatures:
>
> Sub F(x As Short, _
>         Optional y As Integer = 10, _
>         Optional z As Long = 20)
>
> These are the method's signatures:
>   • F(Short) 
>   • F(Short, Integer) 
>   •   F(Short, Integer, Long)

So I think you found a bug.  It is a mild one, it gets resolved anyway at the call site, you'll get error BC30521, "Overload resolution failed".  You can report it at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: thank you for the research, feel free to report to connect.microsoft.com as Hans deserves the credit for figuring this one out. We just noticed an odd behavior...